# C++ Extract the contents of an istream and copy to another

Tags: c++, copy, istream

I was wondering how I would go about sucking out the contents of one istream and saving it in another istream. It seems explicit copying doesn't seem to work for streams, so I was wondering if this could be achieved instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just want a change buffers:

```c++
int main()
{
    std::istream copy(nullptr);
    copy.rdbuf(std::cin.rdbuf());
    std::cin.rdbuf(nullptr);

    for (std::string word; copy >> word; ) {
        std::cout << word << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: this would still be a single istream though

Comment: instead just make a reference to it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to an istream ("i" means input).  But if you want to create a new one, you can:

```
vector<char> str;
copy(istream_iterator<char>(cin), istream_iterator<char>(), back_inserter(str));
istringstream result(str);
```

Now you have a new `istream` which contains the contents from `cin` (or any other existing `istream`).

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and this seems wrong to the compiler: `istringstream result(str)`, the error message: `No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called`.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: in that case, try `istringstream result(string(&str[0]))` to explicitly construct the string before the stream.